# Azure Management Portal Silverlight Version

Tags: azure, acs

I need to use the old Silverlight Windows Azure Management Portal for my ACS services. As I remember, the url for that site is http://windows.azure.com. But it redirects to the http://manage.windowsazure.com all the time.

Is there anyway that I can find the silverlight site back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same results.  To access your ACS web management portal use this URL and replace the first domain with your service.

```
  https://YOURSERVICE.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/mgmt/web
```

Answer (score 3):

Im the new portal you can click in te top-right corner (where your email is shown) and that will open the avatar-bar which includes a link to the previous Silverlight portal.

Answer (score 2):

After it redirects you to manage.windowsazure.com, go to the upper right corner - where it says your name, and after clicking on your name, there is the option "Previous portal".